# Why aren't my QRadioButtons appearing in my QGroupBox?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my code, it's super simple:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGroupBox* genderGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Gender", ui->centralWidget);
    QVBoxLayout* genderGroupBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(genderGroupBox);
    QRadioButton* maleRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Male", genderGroupBox);
    QRadioButton* femaleRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Female", genderGroupBox);

    genderGroupBoxLayout->addStretch();
}
```

but for some reason my program looks like this:

[image: program output]

I've programmed in Qt quite a bit and I am totally baffled as to why the radio buttons aren't showing up inside the group box.  I've tried explicitly adding them with

```
genderGroupBoxLayout->addWidget(maleRadioButton);
```

and manually adding the layout via

```
genderGroupBox->setLayout(genderGroupBoxLayout);
```

even though neither should be necessary because of how they were constructed.  It looks like the radio buttons don't have any parent at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm coding using Qt Creator 3.1.2 on a mac.  Also the .ui file is empty of everything except centralWidget, which has a grid layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts) :

> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically reparent
>   the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of
>   the widget on which the layout is installed.

Your code should look like the following :

```
QGroupBox* genderGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Gender");
QVBoxLayout* genderGroupBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
QRadioButton* maleRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Male");
QRadioButton* femaleRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Female");

genderGroupBoxLayout->addWidget(maleRadioButton);
genderGroupBoxLayout->addWidget(femaleRadioButton);
genderGroupBoxLayout->addStretch();
genderGroupBox->setLayout(genderGroupBoxLayout);

ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(genderGroupBox);
```

Comment: In fact, there's no need for any of those to be allocated on the heap. The layout and all of the widgets can simply be members of the `MainWindow` class.